# Can't Get Apache To Start

Tags: apache-2.2, zend-server

Background:  I am running a site built with the Zend framework.  The site is hosted on a remote RHEL5 server, and also uses Zend server instead of the generic LAMP stack.

About an hour ago my site just died.  After trying to restart the webserver and the entire zend server, I resorted to rebooting the server, making sure to apache processes were running, and then starting the zend server.  Next I checked the status of Apache, but it said it was not running.  I started Apache and checked the status again, and it's still not running.  Here is a C&P from my terminal window:

```
[root@dealerPortal bin]# /usr/local/zend/bin/zendctl.sh restart
httpd (no pid file) not running
/usr/local/zend/bin/apachectl stop [OK]
/usr/local/zend/bin/apachectl start [OK]
Stopping Zend Server GUI [Lighttpd] [OK]
spawn-fcgi: child spawned successfully: PID: 6814
Starting Zend Server GUI [Lighttpd] [OK]
[root@dealerPortal bin]# /usr/local/zend/apache2/bin/apachectl status
Apache is not running..
[root@dealerPortal bin]# /usr/local/zend/apache2/bin/apachectl start
/usr/local/zend/apache2/bin/apachectl start [OK]
[root@dealerPortal bin]# /usr/local/zend/apache2/bin/apachectl status
Apache is not running..
```

I am utterly perplexed as to why Apache isn't running.  This is a production site, so I need get it back up ASAP. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are zendctl.sh and apachectl looking for PID file in the same place?  Is apache actually running after you start it or are you just getting the OK message?  Are lighttpd and apache configured for the same port? they shouldn't be.

Comment: You need to check the Apache and Zend logs. Start in /var/log

Comment: try `ps -elf` to see if there are `httpd` (or `apache`) processes actually running -- if so you should be able to see the actual command use to start the server, including where the logs are and where the pidfile is stored.  Logs are usually in /var/log/www or /var/log/httpd; see what messages are in error log and post back.  If there are apache/httpd instances running, kill them (`sudo kill -9 <process_id>`) and make sure to delete the pidfile, then restart.

Comment: have you checked with `apachectl -t`? maybe the conf files were changed?